# How to access dataframe rows based on user input

Tags: python, pandas, csv, file, user-input

How can I access dataframe rows based on user input? Let's say I have a csv file with countries in the world. The first column would be "continent", the second would be "country" and the third would be "city".

How can I get all the values from "city" if I choose a certain country?

```
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")


if continent == 'europe':
country = input("Choose a country:")
for index, row in enumerate(df.index):
    city = df.values[index]
    print(city)
```

With this code I'm just printing out every city in every country. I want to only get German cities if I type Germany. Where do I place the "country" variable in the for loop?

Comment: Can you show a sample of your dataframe?   Do you have a multiindex for rows?  Or, do you have the default range index and three columns?

Comment: I'm currently on my phone so I can't show a sample right now, but I have default range index and three columns.

Comment: `df.query('country == @country')['city'].to_list()`  No need for loops.  Try this after your input line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a for loop for this.
Assuming your dataframe columns are called "continent", "country", and "city", something like this should work:

```
input_country= input("Choose a country:")
print (df.loc[df.country==input_country].city)
```